# Remove html element programatically from web browser control

Tags: c#, webbrowser-control

i search google and found few line of code to do so. here is the code

```
using Microsoft.mshtml;
....
{
...
    // To Remove     
    HTMLDocumentClass htmldoc = wbCtrl.Document.DomDocument as HTMLDocumentClass;
    IHTMLDOMNode node = htmldoc.getElementById("xBar") as IHTMLDOMNode;
    node.parentNode.removeChild(node);
...
}
```

i am getting error for mshtml reference but i add the library from this path **C:\Program Files\Microsoft.NET\Primary Interop Assemblies and add the dll called Microsoft.mshtml.dll**

but still got the error. so help me what to add as a result the above code i can use. i am running my apps VS2010 IDE.

Comment: for my own ref http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18935/The-most-complete-C-Webbrowser-wrapper-control

Comment: I posted an answer to the question you answered today.

Answer (score 0):

Old answer from your recent question reposted, as it is applicable:

```
//in class def
private bool firstTime;
//in method
bool firstTimeLcl = firstTime
firstTime = false;
if (firstTimeLcl)
{
//write header
} 
else
{
String.Replace(/*closing tags*/, "");
}
//write everything within body
//write closing tags
```

Comment: i just really do not understand what r u trying to do.

Comment: It should be plenty clear. If it's the first time round, write the HML opening tags (header). Then, if it isn't, we get rid of the closing tags. Then we add the extra bit to your body, and then we close the document again.

Comment: i asked how to remove any html element progrramatically from web browser control not add anything.

Comment: String.replace is there for that.

Comment: That isn't clear at all. I want to remove elements and he is showing something talking about strings. I understand what he may be thinking, but not specifying where this should go or what it should be encompassed in makes it not helpful.